# Index to Solr from Android application

Tags: android, solr, solrj

I have tried to find a solution how to index my document from my android app,

I have tried Solrj to do that, but it seems not compatible with android applications

do you have any suggestions to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What about using regular POST to Solr?

Example of Curl:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update?commit=true --data-binary @data.json -H Content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Docs for:

- [JSON](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON)
- [XML](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages)
- [CSV](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateCSV)

Comment: I have used it to make request, but for indexing I didn't find how to index using post.